# Consulta sql muestra fila extra con valores null

Tags: mysql, select, sql, null

Cuando hago una consulta a una base de datos con un formato parecido al de la siguiente, siempre obtengo una fila de valores null. Me gustaría saber por qué sucede esto y como podría evitarlo.

```
SELECT c.`Code`, c.`Name`
FROM `country` c
WHERE c.`Name` = 
(SELECT cty.`Name`
FROM `city` cty
WHERE c.`Capital` = cty.`ID`)
ORDER BY c.`SurfaceArea`;
```

La base de datos utilizada se llama world (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html).

Comment: A mí me aparece sin esa fila extra. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bB3sfSGqjGUyFE7Z84BFZx/0

Comment: Creo que se debe al gestor que estoy usando. Es el sql workbench. Viendo que desde la siguiente web se muestra correctamente, me quedo más tranquilo.

Comment: Puede ser cuestión de valores almacenados en tu base de datos, ya sea al crearla o por modificaciones posteriores. Los datos los tomé de la liga que compartiste.

Comment: Según el **fiddle**  de @LuisCazares, todo parece correcto con el operador **IN**. Cual es realmente tu problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede ocurrir que la siguiente SELECT, no devuelva ningún resultado:

```
SELECT cty.`Name`
FROM `city` cty
WHERE c.`Capital` = cty.`ID`
```

Aun así prueba con el operador **IN** en vez de **=**:

```
SELECT c.`Code`, c.`Name`
FROM `country` c
WHERE c.`Name` IN <-- Todos los registros dentro de la Select siguiente
(SELECT cty.`Name`
FROM `city` cty
WHERE c.`Capital` = cty.`ID`)
ORDER BY c.`SurfaceArea`;
```

Comment: Continua apareciendo la fila null. Sucede lo mismo en el caso de que haga una consulta SELECT * FROM country;

Comment: @DavidCiria: Has comprobado si tienes datos en la tabla `country`?

Comment: Si que tengo datos. Creo que el problema se debe al gestor de bases de datos (sql workbench), gracias.